# How to increase size of a Grid that Contains a Drawing Canvas in a Stack Layout in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code below creates what is shown in the picture below where the label's text is from an API I am calling. Also the drawing canvas is taken from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/SkiaSharpForms/Demos/Demos/SkiaSharpFormsDemos. I was wondering how to make the drawing canvas more larger in height? Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             xmlns:tt="clr-namespace:TouchTracking"
             x:Class="MathKumu.Pages.WorkPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding EquationString}" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Put Answer Here" />
            <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                                   PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface"/>
                <Grid.Effects>
                    <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                                    TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
                </Grid.Effects>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: Specify a Height, or use VerticalOptions to tell the Grid how to grow.

Comment: I tried the code below and it did not work

Comment: <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                                   PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
                <Grid.Effects>

Comment: <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                                    TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
                </Grid.Effects>
            </Grid>
@Jason

Comment: Set the height and vertical options of the grid

Comment: @Jason Do you mean <Grid BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="Fill">? Would I set HeighRequest to a number?

Comment: Try changing `<StackLayout>` to `<Grid>`. `StackLayout` will shrink to the size of its children.

Comment: @hvaughan3 Thank you the person who answered my question showed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `StackLayout` to a `Grid` and specify that `Row 2` has a `Height` of `*`. That will force `Row 2` to consume all extra space.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             xmlns:tt="clr-namespace:TouchTracking"
             x:Class="MathKumu.Pages.WorkPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding EquationString}" />
            <Entry Grid.Row="1" Placeholder="Put Answer Here" />
            <Grid Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="White">
                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                                   PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface"/>
                <Grid.Effects>
                    <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                                    TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
                </Grid.Effects>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help.